# How to test a moderated mediation model in which data on dependent and independent variables comes from different sources?

Tags: regression, spss, mediation

I am trying to test a moderated mediation model in which I have gathered data from two groups of participants: managers and staff members. Managers answered the questions on independent variables (let say A,B,C) and the moderator (D), and staff members answered questions on dependent variables (F,G) and the mediator (E). A hypothetical image of my research model is attached.
[image]

This is NOT leader-member dyad data as I was not able to match the respondents.

Can I run a regression analysis on this data to test my hypotheses? If not, what could be any other technique to test the model?

Comment: You need to link the two sets of responses by re-framing the analysis in terms of what it's *about* - teams, projects, products?